# How to fix linking issue in titlesec?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119198/6574038) I'm using `titlesec` package to get my headers in sans serif.

Looks pretty; however there seems to be a problem with latex titlesec package using `rmarkdown`. The bookmarks are confused, also the linking within the document is not working well (i.e. clicking the bookmark doesn't jump correctly to the header).

I'm showing an image of Acrobat Reader bookmarks with titlesec line activated (left) and commented out (right):

[image]

Any suggestions? I'm using MiKTeX.

***MWE:***

```
---
output: pdf_document
subparagraph: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lipsum}  # produces dummy text
- \usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}  # titlesec line
---

# Header1
\lipsum[1]

## Header1.1
\lipsum[1-7]

### Header1.1.1
\lipsum[1-7]

## Header1.2
\lipsum[1-7]

### Header1.2.1
\lipsum[1-7]
```

***Session info:***

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19      rstudioapi_0.8    knitr_1.20        magrittr_1.5      hms_0.4.2        
 [6] devtools_1.13.6   munsell_0.5.0     colorspace_1.3-2  rlang_0.2.2       tools_3.5.1      
[11] data.table_1.11.8 rio_0.5.10        withr_2.1.2       htmltools_0.3.6   readxl_1.1.0     
[16] yaml_2.2.0        rprojroot_1.3-2   digest_0.6.18     tibble_1.4.2      crayon_1.3.4     
[21] zip_1.0.0         curl_3.2          memoise_1.1.0     evaluate_0.12     haven_1.1.2      
[26] rmarkdown_1.10    openxlsx_4.1.0    cellranger_1.1.0  compiler_3.5.1    pillar_1.3.0     
[31] scales_1.0.0      forcats_0.3.0     backports_1.1.2   foreign_0.8-71    pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Comment: In the final document (pdf) the TOC and headers are fine for me.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer THX, I've edited the question to clarify a bit.

Comment: I see the same bookmarks either way.  I'm on a Mac; maybe this is an issue with your TeX version?

Comment: @user2554330 Hm I don't know, at the moment I'm using MiKTeX.

Comment: @user2554330 and I tried pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex rmarkdown output option with no difference.

Comment: I'm using TeXLive 2016, which is  not current.  I think TeXLive is available on Windows as well, though MikTeX is the more commonly used distribution.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Arch Linux, titlesec version 2.10.2, which seems to be the [current version](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec).

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on MikTeX with `titlesec` v2.10.2. The problem seems to be the line `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` in the intermediate TEX file. See [here](https://pastebin.com/SLHfAS9w) for a MWE (this is the file produced by pandoc; I removed all the fluff). The problem occurs (only) with line 5, not otherwise.

Comment: So it looks like `titlesec` somehow clashes with setting `secnumdepth`. It is probably easier to avoid titlesec than altering the pandoc template and finding a workaround for not using `secnumdepth`.